# DataFrame to dict with one column as the key and multiple columns as a value

Tags: python, pandas

```
      id       GIVEN_NAMES FAMILY_NAME     DATE_OF_BIRTH
0     tttyy12  8000004199  8000004199      19660410
1     tttyy13  8000004274  8000004274      19980209
```

This is a dataframe output

I need to convert this into dict

```
{'tttyy12': ['8000004199','8000004199','19660410'], 'tttyy13' : ['8000004274' ,'8000004274' ,     '19980209']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply()` on rows and convert row value to list with `Series.values.tolist()`.

```py
l = df.set_index('id').apply(lambda row: {row.name: row.values.tolist()}, axis=1).tolist()
```

```
print(l)

[{'tttyy12': [8000004199, 8000004199, 19660410]}, {'tttyy13': [8000004274, 8000004274, 19980209]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the index to the `id` column, then convert to an index-based dictionary.  From there you can use a comprehension to turn the value dictionaries to lists.

```
{
    k: list(v.values()) 
    for k, v 
    in df.set_index('id').to_dict('index').items()
}
# returns:
{'tttyy12': [8000004199, 8000004199, 19660410],
 'tttyy13': [8000004274, 8000004274, 19980209]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, however, another option is to use the `pd.DataFrame.groupby()`.

```
dict([(key, value) for (key, value) in dt.groupby("id")])
```