# PySpark df to dict: one column as key, the other as value

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I have a PySpark Data-frame like this:

```
+----+-----------------+
|  id|    director_name|
+----+-----------------+
| 123|    james cameron|
|  32|   gore verbinski|
|  34|       sam mendes|
|2345|christopher nolan|
| 987|      doug walker|
+----+-----------------+
```

I need a dict like this:

```
{123: james cameron, 32: gore verbinski, ...}
```

I have found a solution using [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301208/dataframe-to-dict-with-one-column-as-the-key-and-multiple-columns-as-a-value) df, but I need to work as parallelized as possible, therefore I'm looking for a spark solution...

Comment: Both answers, Vaebhav's and notNull's, work perfectly! I accepted Vaebhav's because it is 40% faster :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RDDs have built in function [asDict()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Row.asDict.html) that allows to represent each row as a dict.

A Spark Dataframe `sparkDF`, can converted to an rdd & apply asDict() to get the desired result

Another way can be to convert your Spark DataFrame [toPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html) and apply as demonstrated under the link - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301208/dataframe-to-dict-with-one-column-as-the-key-and-multiple-columns-as-a-value)

## Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
| 123|    james cameron
|  32|   gore verbinski
|  34|       sam mendes
|2345|christopher nolan
| 987|      doug walker
""".split("|")


input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, input_str[1:]))

n = len(input_values)

cols = ['id','director_name']

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,n,2)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF.show()

+----+-----------------+
|  id|    director_name|
+----+-----------------+
| 123|    james cameron|
|  32|   gore verbinski|
|  34|       sam mendes|
|2345|christopher nolan|
| 987|      doug walker|
+----+-----------------+
```

## asDict

```
imm_dict = sparkDF.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict()).collect()

id_dict = {d['id']: d['director_name'] for d in imm_dict}

id_dict

{'123': 'james cameron',
 '32': 'gore verbinski',
 '34': 'sam mendes',
 '2345': 'christopher nolan',
 '987': 'doug walker'}
```

## ToPandas

```
id_dict = sparkDF.toPandas().set_index('id').T.to_dict('records')[0]

{'123': 'james cameron',
 '32': 'gore verbinski',
 '34': 'sam mendes',
 '2345': 'christopher nolan',
 '987': 'doug walker'}
```

Comment: `id_dict = {d['id']: d['director_name'] for d in sparkDF.collect()}` # without row.asDict()

Answer (score 2):

Use spark inbuilt functions **`map_from_arrays, to_json, collect_list`** with **`groupBy`**.

**`Example:`**

```
sparkDF.\
groupBy(lit(1)).\
agg(to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(col("id")),collect_list(col("director_name")))).alias("dict")).\
select("dict").\
collect()[0][0]
#'{"123":"james cameron","32":"gore verbinski","34":"sam mendes","2345":"christopher nolan","987":"doug walker"}'
```