# PySpark create external dictionary from a dataframe column of strings

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
data = [
    ("100", 'the boy wants go to school'),
    ("200", 'he is a good boy'),
    ("300", 'he likes to play football in the school')
]
schema = ['id', 'description']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
```

I want to create an **external dictionary** (i.e. not as a new column; I need to access the dictionary separately later) from **the words in each row in the 'description' column**.

Desired output i.e. my dictionary should be:

```
the: 2
boy: 1
wants: 1
he: 2
school: 2
play: 1
...
```

I know how to do this using pandas. How can I do it **using PySpark**?

(I've tried MapType, udf etc. but could not succeed.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    ("100", "the boy wants go to school"),
    ("200", "he is a good boy"),
    ("300", "he likes to play football in the school"),
]
schema = ["id", "description"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

df = (
    df.withColumn("word", f.explode(f.split(f.col("description"), " ")))
    .groupBy("word")
    .count()
    .sort("count", ascending=False)
)

res = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict()).collect()
res = {d["word"]: d["count"] for d in res}

print(res)
```

Another way for the export of the dict can be to convert your Spark DataFrame toPandas as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68968116/pyspark-df-to-dict-one-column-as-key-the-other-as-value)

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for! BTW. toPandas won’t work for me as I have really big data...